# BASH tar упаковать папку в другой папке

Tags: linux, bash, tar

При подобной команде упаковывается полный путь

```
tar -cvpf test.tar.gz mypc/test/testdir
```

он упаковывает полностью папку `mypc/test/testdir`

Мне нужно заархивировать определенную папку в другой папке так, чтобы корневая папка не попала в архив, а заархивировалось только `test/testdir`, может знает кто команду?
Искал в мануалах не нашел.

Answer (score 3):

можно воспользоваться опцией `-C каталог`, означающей «на время создания архива сделать текущим указанный каталог».

т.е., вместо

```
$ tar -cvpf test.tar.gz mypc/test/testdir
```

используйте такую команду:

```
$ tar -cvpf test.tar.gz -C mypc test/testdir
```

---

по поводу местоположения файла, указанного опцией `-f файл`, не беспокойтесь — он будет создан там, откуда запущена команда.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать сначала перейти в нужную вам директорию, примерно так:

```
cd ./mypc && tar -cvpf test.tar.gz ./test/testdir && cd -
```

И кстати, чтобы сжатый архив (`.gz`) получить, надо к `-cvpf` ещё ключ `-z` добавить ([man](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=tar&category=1)).

Comment: Есть же опция `-C`